# Module pattern callback implementation

Tags: javascript, module, callback

I'm rewriting a simple app using HTML/CSS/JavaScript that creates animations with images using intervals, and there's a bunch of buttons that controls these animations.

It's scaling and becoming really messed up, with logic mixed with DOM manipulations via jQuery all through one javascript script file.

So I decided to use the Module design pattern.

Based on my description of the app, is there a problem with this callback implementation for a module?

Or with the module implementation?

In this example, what is the best approach to declare private variables and give access to them through the public api? Getters and setters? Are they really necessary? I want to write readable code but I don't want to over-architect things.

```
(function($) {

  $.Module = function(options){
    var module = {
      options: $.extend({
        callbacks: {
          start: false
        }
      }, options),
      start: function(callback){
        //console.log('private start method');
        if(typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
      }
    }

    // public api
    return {
      start: function(){
        //console.log('public start method');
        module.start(module.options.callbacks.start);
      }
    }
  }

}($));

var myModule = $.Module({
  callbacks: {
    start: function(){
      console.log('start callback!');
    }
  }
})

myModule.start();
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa6xJkA49H3vgN5TYcTR?p=preview) is a sample.

Just because it seems to work to me, and I've seen other implementations that have some code that look like this:

```
callback: function(method) {
    if(typeof method === "function") {
        var args = [];

        for(var x = 1; x <= arguments.length; x++) {
            if(arguments[x]) {
                args.push(arguments[x]);
            }
        }

        method.apply(this, args);
    }
},
```

I'm not sure what this last code is supposed to do. Is it intended to return data to the callback function I registered when instantiating the module? If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a problem with this callback implementation for a module?

Not if this what you want.

> Or with the module implementation?

Your instantiation of the `options` property should probably use a [deep extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), the current one is overwriting the complete `callbacks` object.

> I'm not sure what this other code I found is supposed to do. Is it intended to return data to the callback function

Yes. It does support multiple arguments, using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

> … I registered when instantiating the module?

No, it does not have to do with registration. It will call the `method` that is passed as a parameter to this `callback` function.

Using this code will release you from the need to do that `typeof` check every time. You would just write

```
helper.callback(this.options.callbacks.start, /* optional arguments */)
// instead of
if (typeof this.options.callbacks.start == "function")
    this.options.callbacks.start(/* arguments */)
```

However, until you think that you need this helper you will not need this helper.

Comment: not sure what you meant with "However, until you think that you need this helper you will not need this helper."!

Comment: That you don't need this helper function. Until you realize you want to use it for some reason.